# MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP not working for AS3 code

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to use the drag feature of flash to move a sprite I created. 
I understand that I can add the mouse up event inside of the mouse down event and add to the stage but I would prefer to see if I can get this working first.
Part of the reason I want to use sprite instance mouse up handler is later in code I am referencing the event.target.name for further processing. Below is the code that is giving me the issue with mouse up.

```
var cnt_fat_1:Sprite = new Sprite();
var g : Graphics = cnt_fat_1.graphics;
g.lineStyle(0,0x555555,0.5);
g.beginFill(0xFFffff);
g.drawRect( 0, 0, 25, 25 );
g.endFill( );
cnt_fat_1.x = 20
cnt_fat_1.y = 20

cnt_fat_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, move_choose)
cnt_fat_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, move_stop)

addChild(cnt_fat_1)

function move_choose(event:MouseEvent):void {
event.target.startDrag(true);   
 }

function move_stop(event:MouseEvent):void {
event.target.stopDrag() 
}
```

Comment: What is the "issue"?  It's not working at all?    The mouse up will have to happen over top of the sprite, so if you are dragging quickly the object may lag behind the mouse slightly making it not work.

Comment: Yes the mouse is never lined up with sprite even when I move the mouse very slowly...not exactly sure how to get the mouse to line up. I also notice that when I click on the stage about 40 pixels south of the sprite the sprite is still selected and moves to location of the mouse.

Comment: Yes mouse up event never fires.

Comment: It's because passing `true` to start drag is making it snap to the top/left corner instead of where you actually click making it almost impossible for the mouse to be over the object when you mouse up.    take out the true parameter, or listen for mouse up on the stage.

Comment: yep...that was it. I also noticed that part of the issue was created when I added a textfield to the sprite because height and width of the textfield I added extended beyond the size of the sprite graphic so mouse down event fired when the mouse seemed to be outside the sprite. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You may want to bind the mouseup event to the stage rather than the sprite. That way you get the event even if the mouse cursor isn't hover the sprite. The use of event.currentTarget instead of event.target will allow you to know which sprite dispatched this event.